# setting network in a virtual machine

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I've installed a VMWorkstation  on my pc, on which I have a wifi and Ethernet adapter. as follow:

[image]

The question that I have is, how can I tell  my VM(win10) to use BOTH ports ?
I've been reading  the docs but couldn't solve it, here are the settings that I'm using :
[image]

thanks in advance for any hint !

Comment: Do you mean you want your VM guest to have 2 network adapters one for each host adapter?  If so I imagine you can click add (you can on VBox and Hyper-V so I suppose it is the same) and link one to host Ethernet and one to host Wi-Fi.  I do this.  If you mean you want to have one VM guest adapter simultaneously connect to 2 host adapters I'm not sure if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vmware network editor, you can specify the association between the VMWare names and the external (host networks). Is this what you are asking?
"VMware Network editor" is a program on your windows host.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2MKY.png)